# В контроллере UserController, сделать действие all, которое будет выводить список всех юзеров на экран

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Задание: В контроллере UserController, сделайте действие all, которое будет выводить список всех юзеров на экран. Пусть это действие будет доступно по адресу следующего вида: /user/all/ (параметров тут никаких не будет).

```
namespace Project\Controllers;

use \Core\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = [
            1 => ['name' => 'user1', 'age' => '23', 'salary' => 1000],
            2 => ['name' => 'user2', 'age' => '24', 'salary' => 2000],
            3 => ['name' => 'user3', 'age' => '25', 'salary' => 3000],
            4 => ['name' => 'user4', 'age' => '26', 'salary' => 4000],
            5 => ['name' => 'user5', 'age' => '27', 'salary' => 5000],
        ];
    }
    public function show($params)
    {
        print_r($this->users[$params['id'] ]);
    }
    public function info($params)
    {
        print_r($this->users[$params['id']][$params['key']]);
    }
    public function all($params)
    {
        print_r($this->users[$params]);
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, как сделать правильно.

Comment: *как сделать правильно.* - всего то надо, как я понимаю, распечатать массив?

Comment: я так сначала и думал, но в роуте же все. как сказано в задании  
new Route('/users/all/', 'users', 'all') - без параметров, так что ошибка Notice: Undefined index: all

Comment: а как вы используете параметр при выводе списка?

Comment: Ну в прошлых заданиях new Route('/users/:id/', 'users', 'show') - где параметр id в строке подставить любое значение из массива и он выведет

Comment: я не знаю вашу реализацию, но по идее  `new Route('/users/all/', 'users', 'all')` должно означать вызов `Users::all()` - то есть без параметров

Comment: Нужно было порядок в роуте поменять и заработало